# How to enter LLDB command via Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, lldb

How can I enter an LLDB command via Android studio?

According to [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig.html):

> In addition to the normal Android Studio UI, the debugger window has an LLDB tab that lets you enter LLDB commands during debugging. You can enter the same commands that Android Studio uses to display information in the debugger UI, and you can perform additional operations.

Great! ... But where is the "LLDB tab"? There is indeed a "Console" tab in the Debug tab which says:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

But text typed here followed by an enter does nothing, paused or not paused.

Comment: LLDB is not currently working in Android Studio 2.1. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=204760

Comment: @Jon -- I'm running 2.2.3

Comment: The detail in the issue should give you an idea of how LLDB works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LLDB tab was missing because I had "android-gradle-native-java" selected instead of "android-gradle-native".

[image]